# Shiurim collection online

Tags: product-recommendation, torah-study, internet, adult-learning

What good online sources are there for shiurim? More like on random topics, not text based.

(Imagine someone who does manual labor all day so their brain is open but doesn't have time to actually sit down and learn.)

Comment: http://insidechassidus.org   http://torahcafe.com

Comment: Please explain what you mean by your 2nd sentence. What type of "random topics", and what do you mean by "not text based"?

Comment: @DanF I mean that you shouldn't need to have any book. Imagine a Gemara class vs a topic class. The Gemara class isn't trying to teach you a topic, the focus is the text. A "topic class" is not concerned with you knowing the text (though obviously it must be based on text), rather the focus is that you come out with and idea. I gave the example because I didn't know how to write it more clearly.

Answer (score 4):

- [YU Torah](http://www.yutorah.org/index.cfm_)
- [Torah any Time](https://www.torahanytime.com/#/)
- [Virtual Beit Midrash](http://etzion.org.il/en_)
- [Torah Downloads](https://torahdownloads.com/)
- [Kol HaLashon](http://www.kolhalashon.com/New/HomePage/KhlHome2.aspx?Lang=English&English=True).

I am not so familiar with these different sites, but they all seem to qualify. YU Torah alone is a tremendous repository with over 100000 shiurim of all kinds.

Answer (score 3):

Here are some other sites I have used and like

- [Aish](https://aishaudio.com/) - a bit more beginner focused
- [torah.org](https://torah.org/) - split by shiurim by "complexity level"
- [The Shmuz](https://theshmuz.com/) - focused on yeshiva graduates
- [TorahMedia](https://torahmedia.com/) - thousands of shiurim from multiple rabbanim
- [TorahWeb](http://www.torahweb.org/index.html)

If you need Hebrew sites, ask in the comments

Comment: Do you have hebrew sites?

Answer (score 1):

http://ohr.edu http://www.parsha.net/ http://rabbikaganoff.com/ http://rabbisacks.org/covenant-conversation-homepage/

You can also get these emailed to you on a weekly basis. Also note that some of the sites mentioned in other answers can also be obtained on a regular basis via email, especially those connected with the parsha of the week.

https://www.torahanytime.com/ has a large number of shiurim that is constantly being added to. You can subscribe to any of the lecturers and be notified via email when a new shiur by your favorites are added.