# Is there a daily / weekly reading?

Tags: talmud-gemara, torah-study, tanach

Is there something like a daily or weekly reading of the Torah and/or Talmud? Where could they be found? Is there maybe a commentary about them too?

Comment: Are you referring to Daf Yomi or the weekly Shnaim Mikra veechad Targum?

Comment: IIRC, Chaba"d has a daily schedule called "Chita"s". I think it stands for "Chumash / Tehillim / Tanya"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [5 books of the Torah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torah#Pentateuch) are generally read in their entirety once a year. They are divided into sections, commonly called Parshiyot (plural. Singular: Parasha, or Parashat HaShavua). Chabad.org seems to have links to content related to the weekly Parasha [here](http://www.chabad.org/parshah/default_cdo/jewish/Torah-Portion.htm/). Some people like to study a page of Talmud a day, concluding it every seven and a half years. This is called [Daf Yomi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daf_Yomi). There are an almost endless number of commentaries on the Torah and the Talmud, in numerous languages. One popular translation of the Torah, that includes a commentary as well, is [The Living Torah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Living_Torah_and_Nach). One popular translation and commentary to the Talmud is [Artscroll's Schottenstein edition](http://www.artscroll.com/Categories/TLM.html).

The Talmud would probably be poorly suited for beginners. Practical Jewish law and Jewish thought would probably be more useful (cf. [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/55493/8775)). Resources abound. For a list of websites that contain large amounts of relevant material in different media, see [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/86567/8775).

One daily program is called [Hok L'Yisrael](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chok_l%27Yisrael). It includes daily study of Tanakh, Mishna, Talmud, Halakha (Jewish law), Mussar (ethics), and mysticism. It is available in English [here](http://echok.com/).

Answer (score 3):

@mevaqesh answered the first part of your question about the Torah being read a parsha a week. Additionally, the parsha of the week is studied in a procedure called [Shnayim Mikra V'Echad Targum](http://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Shnayim_Mikra_V%27Echad_Targum).

Additionally. the second part of the question asks about the talmud. This is studied in a procedure known as [Daf Yomi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daf_Yomi) There are numerous web sites which contain daily shiurim for each daf of the daf yomi so that people can *attend* a virtual shiur if they cannot attend in person. One example of this is [YUTorah Online](http://www.yutorah.org/daf.cfm)

A [Daf Yomi Calendar](http://www.dafyomi.org/machzor.php?machzor=13) showing the current 13th cycle is published showing the dates each daf is scheduled to be learned.

[Daf Yomi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daf_Yomi)

> Daf Yomi (Hebrew: דף יומי‬, Daf Yomi, "page of the day" or "daily
>   folio") is a daily regimen of learning the Oral Torah and its
>   commentaries (also known as the Gemara), in which each of the 2,711
>   pages of the Babylonian Talmud are covered in sequence. A daf, or
>   blatt in Yiddish, consists of both sides of the page. Under this
>   regimen, the entire Talmud is completed, one day at a time, in a cycle
>   of seven and a half years.
>
> The first cycle of Daf Yomi commenced on the first day of Rosh
>   Hashanah 5684 (11 September 1923), with tens of thousands of Jews in
>   Europe, America and Israel learning the first daf of the first
>   tractate of the Talmud, Berachot. To show support for the idea, the
>   Gerrer Rebbe, Rabbi Avraham Mordechai Alter, learned the first daf of
>   Berachot in public on that day. On 12 November 1924 Tractate Berachot
>   was completed, with small siyums (celebrations marking the completion
>   of study of a Talmudic tractate) in local communities. At that time,
>   Rabbi Shapiro published a calendar for the entire cycle of Daf Yomi
>   study.

The study of the daf yomi has continued uninterrupted since then.

[History of the Daf Yomi](http://new.steinsaltz.org/daf-history/)

> In August 1923, at the First International Congress of the Agudath
>   Israel World Movement in Vienna, Rabbi Meir Shapiro proposed uniting
>   the Jewish people worldwide through the daily study of a page of
>   Talmud. The “Daf Yomi” tradition continues today as thousands
>   diligently study the designated page of the day. Daily classes
>   dedicated specifically to the study of Daf Yomi can be found in Jewish
>   communities all across the globe.
>
> With 2,711 pages in the Talmud, each Daf Yomi study cycle takes about
>   seven and a half years. On March 1, 2005, a much-celebrated ceremony
>   known as the Siyum HaShas marked the 11th completion of the entire
>   Talmud by Daf Yomi readers around the world.

Comment: Note that I mention daf yomi as well...